# Hide all Relative Layout with a Function except one we choose

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created 5 Relative Layouts in Android Studio Project (This will be more that 40) with same size. I also create Buttons so that if Someone Clicks on **Lesson 1** button than Only layout1(id of first Layout) Layout Shows on the Screen and Other Layout automatically Hide, if user clicks on **Lesson 2** Button than layout2(id of second layout) show and rest hides automatically, and so on...

Can anyone tell the Logic that I can use to do this. And if there is another best way to do this pls tell....
This is my Lessons.java file

```
public class Lessons extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //Relative Layout's Variables Declaration here
    RelativeLayout r[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lessons);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lessons, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(Lessons.this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch (id){
            case R.id.lesson_1:
                hideRelativeLayout(R.id.layout1);
                break;
            case R.id.lesson_2:
                hideRelativeLayout(R.id.layout2);
                break;
         /*Buttons onSelect Event upto 40*/

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    protected void hideRelativeLayout(int current){
       /*Code that Shows only current Layout and hide rest of all layouts*/

    }
}
```

and this is my activity_lessons.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relLay"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.kaliattacks.evilandroid.hackinginhindi.Lessons"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_lessons">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <!--This is Layout 1-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is Layer 1"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--This is Second Layout-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is another layer"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    <!--This is Third Layout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is Third Layout Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--This is Fourth Layout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is Fourth Layout Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--Fifth Layout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is Fifth Layout Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all `RelativeLayout id` in an `Integer ArrayList` like

```
ArrayList<Integer> relativeLayoutIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

then in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // add all relativelayout id to arraylist
    relativeLayoutIdList.add(R.id.layout1);
    relativeLayoutIdList.add(R.id.layout2);
    ...

}
```

and in your `hideRelativeLayout`

```
protected void hideRelativeLayout(int current){
   for (int i = 0, len = relativeLayoutIdList.size(); i < len; i++){
       if(relativeLayoutIdList.get(i) == current){
            // visible current relativelayout
            (RelativeLayout)  findViewById(relativeLayoutIdList.get(i)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }else{
            // hide all rest relativelayout
            (RelativeLayout)  findViewById(relativeLayoutIdList.get(i)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
   }
}
```

Suggest: I see you use `NavigationView`, you can use mutilple `Fragment` in `NavigationView` instead of create many `RelativeLayout`
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: I have tied this first but when I run my App on Android than Error appear that my App Stopped Working and thanks for giving link for Fragment-Navigation-Drawer :)

Answer (score 2):

1) First you can hide all the views inside your relLay

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLay);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

2) Then show the layout you want

```
 RelativeLayout activeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutX);
 activeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

So your final function will be

public void hidelAllLayoutsExcept(RelativeLayout activeLayout)
{

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLay);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

RelativeLayout activeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutX);
activeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

}